# How to see memory utilisation of user java classes?

Tags: java, memory-management, jprofiler

I want to analyse the memory consumption on the basis of different class files, other than the java provided classes (String,etc). I tried JProfiler, jmap and jhat - all provide the information about java classes, but nothing about the custom classes.

Is there any way to see the memory utilisation of the classes which I have written in the web application?

Answer (score 2):

The heap walker in JProfiler shows you this information:

[image]

after you click the "calculate estimated retained sizes" link above the table. The result is shown in the "Retained Size" column.

Answer (score 0):

Yourkit has excellent memory telemetry where you can analyze class level memory.
https://www.yourkit.com/docs/java/help/memory_telemetry.jsp

JVisualVM has also memory snapshot for class level but not as good as Yourkit. 
https://visualvm.java.net/snapshots.html